# How to manage users roles in WSO2 MI (EI-7)?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

in former versions of WSO2 Enterprise Integrator we could manage lists of roles by users via the manager web console.
With WSO2 EI-7 micro-integrator and wso2mi-dashboard I find no means to manage any roles.  All we can do is manage users, not a word about roles.   So what ?

Thanks,
Bernard

Comment: WSO2 MI has a role concept for users. But to enable it you have to configure an RDBMS or LDAP user store. For more info, refer the docs, https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/setup/user_stores/managing_users/

Comment: Hi Dilan,
I just tried WSO2 MI with a copy of our EI_6.4 DB  we have for users.  The fact is that we can now see users we defined and their associated roles but the dashboard UI does not permit to edit these roles:  it is not possible to manage roles list nor create new ones, remove a role for a user and so on.

Bernard

Comment: it seems to me that roles management has been lost in EI7.1.0